# Java Reading First 2 lines from Text File

Tags: java, text-files

Say I have a text file like this. Does anyone know how I can distinguish the title from the comments, to enable me to store it in a database? Thanks!

(**Edit: Long example truncated)**

> Lost
>
> Danielo2k12 : I agree with SimmsMolly, i was like look for jin as he
>   jumped in after sawyer and then no sign of him, mainly goes into more
>   detail about the meeting in the hatch and more infor about the raft
>   still a worth while watch :D
>
> The Squad
>
> balverio : Yeah, umm, this was a rip off of "The Enemy" but that
>   movies was better. 6/10
>
> Home Movie
>
> SmittShow : dont waste your time 1/5
>
> Silk
>
> Tlcprn : This is such a good series! Expect that Martha will do what
>   she can. She will be quite upset about the outcome when she finds out
>   what has happened to Brendon. Can't wait to see what she has in store
>   for the Farr family! Love, love Martha!!
>
> Qi mou miao ji Wu fu xing
>
> quickmaster : the best movie!!!
>
> I Saw the Sun - (Günesi gördüm)
>
> RuruLover : There aren't any links here....
>
> Hungry for Change
>
> joanofjamaica : I want to see this so badly but I cannot watch any of
>   these links
>
> Unbreakable
>
> ventu_rabbit : It was a fun film, long build up for suspense, but I
>   don't think it was an intelligent, thought-provoking film like all
>   these comments say. I think if you look for something hidden between
>   the lines long enough, you'll find it. It was an average thriller,
>   nothing mind-blowing ... .... etc....

Comment: Holy wall of text Batman!  @user872009, you may want to edit that.

Comment: We don't really need the WHOLE text file... Just the first 3 or 4 lines?

Comment: Shortened into a smaller example that should give the general idea.

Comment: Can we put some metadata (some like @title) in the text file or we just parse the raw text like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably start with something like this. Just read line-by-line. Title, blank line, author and comment, blank line. Split author and comment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\wattsj\\workspace\\youtube\\src\\main\\resources\\cc")));
    while (readReview(br));
}

private static boolean readReview(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    String title = getNextLine(br);
    if (title == null) {
        return false;
    }
    String commentWithAuthor = getNextLine(br);
    if (commentWithAuthor == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Title but end of file before author");
    }
    String[] commentAndAuthor = commentWithAuthor.split(" : ", 2);
    if (commentWithAuthor.length() < 2) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Author but no comment found on the same line");
    }
    String comment = commentAndAuthor[0];
    String author = commentAndAuthor[1];
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println(comment);
    System.out.println(author);
    return true;
}

private static String getNextLine(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    String line;
    if ((line = br.readLine()) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!"".equals(br.readLine())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Expected a blank line");
    }
    return line;
}
```